# "Could not scan for classes inside" error when trying to load a Github repository through composer

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I am trying to autoload a Github repository with the following config in the composer.json file

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type":"package",
            "package": {
                "name": "webdevstudios/taxonomy-single-term",
                "version":"0.2.2",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Taxonomy_Single_Term/archive/master.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Taxonomy_Single_Term.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference":"master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "files": ["class.taxonomy-single-term.php", "walker.class.taxonomy-single-term.php"]
                }
            }
        }
],
```

When run composer update/dumpautoload, I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                   
  Could not scan for classes inside "project1/vendor/  
  webdevstudios/taxonomy-single-term/taxonomy-single-term/" which does not appear to be a file nor a   
  folder
```

Am I missing any specific configuration for the autoload, because "classmap", "psr-0" or any other configuration doesnt work.

Thanks for the help.

PS: the source files exist i "project1/vendor/
      webdevstudios/taxonomy-single-term/". Not sure why I am getting the extra "taxonomy-single-term".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Deleted the vendor folder and composer.lock and ran composer install again. This time everything loaded properly.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, this happens when you have some corrupted files or any composer update has crashed or interrupted.

To solve, just delete the vendor folders and run composer install